# How to monitor memory usage of child process spawned in ruby ?

Tags: ruby, profiling, fork

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the over all memory usage by a parent process spawning child.

Let's say I have main.rb:

```
  100.times do |i|
    fork do
      fib(30)     
    end
  end
  Process.waitall
```

And I want to calculate the memory used by the running the script.

Comment: Have a look at [this blog](http://www.acunote.com/blog/2008/02/make-your-ruby-rails-applications-fast-performance-and-memory-profiling.html).

Comment: Could you ask this question Ruby mailing list? There are also many great people helping the community ? I'm sure you'll will get too many pointers. If you ask.. Use mailing list.